# Running Test file from exercism C#

Tags: c#

I am having trouble getting a test file to run. I can't see what I need to do differently. This is the first exercism project for C#. I think I have the problem solved but I can't get the Test file to run successfully in Microsoft Visual Studio. The goal is to make a function to test whether the year is a leap year.

I want to use the class Year in this file below, in my project it is titled Class1.cs

File with class year:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercism
{
    public class Year
    {   public bool IsLeap(int year)
        {
            if (year % 4 == 0)
                if (year % 100 == 0)
                    if (year % 400 == 0)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                else
                    return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The test file is below. When I try to run it I get the message 'The name 'Year' does not exist in the current context' for each test function below.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Exercism;




[TestFixture]
public class LeapTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Valid_leap_year()
    {
        Assert.That(Year.IsLeap(1996), Is.True);
    }
    [Ignore]
    [Test]
    public void Invalid_leap_year()
    {
        Assert.That(Year.IsLeap(1997), Is.False);
    }

    [Ignore]
    [Test]
    public void Turn_of_the_20th_century_is_not_a_leap_year()
    {
        Assert.That(Year.IsLeap(1900), Is.False);
    }

    [Ignore]
    [Test]
    public void Turn_of_the_25th_century_is_a_leap_year()
    {
        Assert.That(Year.IsLeap(2400), Is.True);
    }
}
```

I know this is a basic question but any help would be appreciated

Comment: exercism practices are very good for learning

Answer (score 2):

You are using `IsLeap` as if it were a static method, but declared it as an instance method.

You can either use `new Year().IsLeap(..)` or set IsLeap to `public static bool IsLeap(...)`.  I'm pretty sure you want the latter.

It's very important to understand the difference between the two, I would recommend reading up on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

public **static** bool IsLeap(int year)